# How to draw dynamic line path on imageView?

Tags: swift, swift3, uibezierpath

I want to draw a line on Image view, Example is below-

[image]

I have a path A to F in imageView.

If I select A and then D- Path will generate like green line and If I select A and F- Path will generate like the red line.

How to do this on image view?

All point(A,B,C,D,E & F) are UIButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I must say your question was not very clear, it took me a while to figure out what you actually want to achieve. I hope I understand correctly. Without simply typing out the actual code you need, this is how I would approach it:

I would create an array with dictionaries containing the letter as key and the point as value, looking something like this:

```
[
["A": CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)],
["B": CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)],
["C": CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)],
["D": CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)],
["E": CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)],
["F": CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)],
]
```

(or nicer, this array could have custom models containing similar info)

Then, use this array to plot the UIButtons on the view, giving each UIButton a reference to the item in the array by subclassing it, e.g the key of the dictionary.

```
CustomButton: UIButton { 
    var key: String?
}
```

Then when tapping the first button, store that key in a local variable named `start` and when tapping the second button store that key in a local variable named `end`. Subsequently, loop through the array and find the matching `start` key and use the values in the array to draw the lines until you find the matching `end` key.

Since I was in the mood, I created a simple playground demo, but this is usually not the way it works. You don't just ask for sample code, you ask for  help to solve a problem.

Anyway, you can find the demo here: https://gist.github.com/pvroosendaal/f1617fe7e164bc94f0d37d3175252e2f

By the way, this is by far the crappiest piece of code I wrote, but it does what you want.

I hope it makes sense, otherwise, please let me know.

Comment: Can you please create a simple demo, take any image or mine as above, and simple draw a line that include two point(A,C)

Comment: Since I was in the mood, I created a simple playground demo, but this is usually not the way it works. You don't just ask for sample code, you ask for help to solve a problem.
Anyway, you can find the demo here: https://gist.github.com/pvroosendaal/f1617fe7e164bc94f0d37d3175252e2f
Btw, this is by far the crappiest piece of code I wrote, but it works.